# Can LWC be configured to appear with Saleforce menu at the top like in classic?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components

I have created an LWC which I put on a vf page since we are in classic. My challenge whether its possible to have the menu tabs at the top  just like in classic as illustrated in the attached images.[image: Classic table with tabs]

[image: Lightning table no tabs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally.

On the visualforce page with the lightning out, I set the header and sidebar to true.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" readOnly="false">
  <apex:includeLightning />
  <div id="LightningComponentid" />
  <script>
    var paymentID = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
    var accID = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.aid}";
    console.log("Payment ID " + paymentID);
    console.log("Received account ID : " + accID);
    $Lightning.use("c:ApplyPaymentsLWCApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:applyPaymentsLWC",
        { recordId: paymentID, accountId: accID },
        "LightningComponentid",
        function (cmp) {
          console.log("LWC Component added in VF page");
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Classic, create a [Visualforce Page that uses Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm), and add the component in the code.

In Lightning, you can create a Lightning App Page in the [Lightning App Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_intro), add the component to the page, and then you can add it as a tab in the Lightning Experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, that is exactly what I have done. The page showing the lightning table has been added to a vf page which has lightning out. But it doesn't open inside saleforce as the one done purely in classic vf page. The url is showing also that its a vf page containing the lightning table if you check.